# Tomcat doesn't start in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I wanted to create a new Spring boot test project with a basic service which returns a message but when I launch the service runs but the Tomcat server does not launch, I don't understand why.

I have Spring Boot version 3.1.4 and Java version 17.

This is what the console returns :

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.4)

2023-10-15T16:37:07.111+02:00  INFO 21264 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Demo4Application        : Starting Demo4Application using Java 17.0.8.1 with PID 21264 (C:\Users\Pilou\Documents\Master2\TP MicroService\demo4\target\classes started by Pilou in C:\Users\Pilou\Documents\Master2\TP MicroService\demo4)
2023-10-15T16:37:07.113+02:00  INFO 21264 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Demo4Application        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-15T16:37:07.469+02:00  INFO 21264 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Demo4Application        : Started Demo4Application in 0.61 seconds (process running for 0.954)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried to force its use by doing this in the pom.xml:

```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

The server then launches but it systematically returns a 404 error.

I should point out that I configured the port in application.properties and that I tried several times to clean it with Maven.

My pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo4</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo4</name>
    <description>demo4</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you try adding the spring starter WEB dependency? From your logs, you  application stops instantly, which means there is no webserver starting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please rewrite dependencies part in the pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then in the root package implement `ApplicationLuncher` class:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationLauncher {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(ApplicationLauncher.class, args);
  }

  @GetMapping
  public String helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

Then start spring application.
To get `Hello World` by curl command, please write `curl http://localhost:8080`.